# Making json files in Scala

Tags: json, scala, file-writing

I am working on a Scala app. I have a method that gives me JSON and I convert it to string using `toString` as follows:

```scala
def myjson(fileName:String){   
   val myJson = myData.getJsonData().toString
}
```

Here `getJsonData()` will give me a `.json`. I want to write this `.json` into a file and save this `.json` in resources section in my project. Format of the file should be ".json". Name of the file is the one which I am getting in above method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be as follow

```scala
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def myjson(fileName:String){
    val myJson = myData.getJsonData().toString
    val path = s"/user/myProject/..../resources/$fileName"
    Files.write(Paths.get(path), myJson.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
}
```

I understand that `fileName: String` will be something like `filename.json`